# How can i use tarantool queue in php?

Tags: php, queue, php-5.6, tarantool

There is a php library https://github.com/tarantool-php/queue, but it requires ext-tarantool, so is there any active maintainable library written purely in php, which allow us to use tarantool queue in php 5.6 or 7?
Or is there any ready package for centos to install ext-tarantool for php5.6?
`yum install php-tarantool` gives following incompatibility error

```
Error: Package: php-tarantool-0.1.0-19.el6.x86_64 (tarantool_1_6)
          Requires: php(zend-abi) = 20090626
          Installed: php-common-5.6.19-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (@remi-php56)
              php(zend-abi) = 20131226-64
```

Comment: AFAIK, there is no repository with this package. As you are using php from "remi-php56", should ask on https://github.com/remicollet/remirepo if possible to add this extension in the repository

Comment: There is new package in remi repository that solves our problem php-tarantool.x86_64 0:0.1.0-1.el6.remi.5.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm the author of the tarantool-php/queue library. I plan to add support for [the pure PHP Tarantool client](https://github.com/tarantool-php/client) in the future, it's just not there yet. Fill free to file a ticket for that ;)

In a meanwhile, as a workaround, you can decorate `Tarantool\Client` with the `\Tarantool` class, e.g.:

```php
use Tarantool\Client;

class Tarantool
{
    private $client;

    public function __construct(Client $client)
    {
        $this->client = $client;
    }

    public function call($functionName, array $args = null)
    {
        $result = $this->client->call($functionName, $args ? $args : []);

        return $result->getData();
    }
}
```

And then use it like this:

```php
use Tarantool\Client;
use Tarantool\Connection\SocketConnection;
use Tarantool\Packer\PurePacker;
use Tarantool\Queue\Queue;

$client = new Client(new SocketConnection(), new PurePacker());
$client = new Tarantool($client);

$queue = new Queue($client, 'foobar');
```

Comment: UPDATE: Since version 0.4.0, tarantool/queue comes with built-in support for the pure PHP client.